# How can I unserialize std class()

Tags: php

I have serialize values in data base, i fetch them from database then when i do

```
<pre>
print_r($DataValues)
</pre>
```

it shows me value like this

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [categories] => a:1:{i:38;s:21:"Summer Market Session";}
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [categories] => a:1:{i:38;s:21:"Summer Market Session";}
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [categories] => a:2:{i:38;s:21:"Summer Market Session";i:39;s:21:"Autumn Market Session";}
    )
```

i want to get only the value after unserializing it, i tried to unserialize but is show bolean false

& when i try to print the value after running for each value it shows me below mentioned error

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

I dont know how i do this i was trying all unserialize tactics what i know & also i tried to store value in array by using foreach loop but i am fail..

Kindly help how can i get value of it after unserilize it...??

Comment: do your class store some references ? (example what mysql_connect returns)

Comment: actually i use a component of joomla it store all the values but i am not retrieving the value in the component & i do'not define a class when i retrieve..

Comment: is it necessary to define a class before unserialize it..now what i am doing is simple fetch the data from data base and storing it in the array..so i get this what i mentioned above..but cant unserialize it nor get values in a for each loop

Comment: How exactly you try to unserialize this, could you show that code here?

Comment: i think in an array it is storing the value for class..like in the key[0] it store serialize value of class

Comment: @raina77ow  
$db  = & JFactory::getDBO();

$sql = "SELECT Query";

$db->setQuery( $sql );

$unserial = $db->loadObjectList();

$data = unserialize($unserial);

Comment: @yes123 i am searching to that file which store data then i will paste that code here..cool?

Comment: unserialize tactics? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, somehow I still can't see the problem. I've reconstructed the data structure you seem to get from DB with this:

```
$testObject             = new stdClass();
$testCategories         = array(38 => 'Summer Market Session');
$testObject->categories = serialize($testCategories);

$anotherTestObject             = new stdClass();
$anotherTestCategories         = $testCategories;
$anotherTestCategories[]       = 'Autumn Market Session';
$anotherTestObject->categories = serialize($anotherTestCategories);

$dataValues = array(
  $testObject, clone $testObject, $anotherTestObject
);

print_r($dataValues);
```

It gave me the same output you'd quoted in your question, so I guess that's a correct reconstruction. To unwrap this data back, simple loop sufficed:

```
foreach ($dataValues as $dataElement) {
  $categories = unserialize($dataElement->categories);
  print_r($categories);
}
```

Or am I doing something wrong?

Anyway, here's [a sandbox](http://codepad.org/isTp6IZ5) to check all this.

Comment: yes @raina77ow you are right, the class is very much similar like you mentioned but the thing is i am retrieving the value in another directory & in that file i doesnot mention that class nor the class file include..So can you guide me what i have to do in this case if class is not mention in that file..

Comment: Cool man i got the unserial data with another key its look like multiple array..but your code really work for me thank you respected @raina770w